# roots of $z^4-4.z^3+6.z^2-4.z-2$

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

What would be the roots of $z^4-4.z^3+6.z^2-4.z-2$, including the complex ones? I don't know how to discover them and in those sites they just give the result.

Comment: Hint: this looks like $(z-1)^{4}-3$. So the roots are translations of the solutions of $w^{4}=3$.

Comment: Hint: if any rational ones exist, it'll be one of $\pm 1, \pm 2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{gather*}
Expanding\ out\ ( z-1)^{4} \ using\ the\ binomial\ theorem,\\
( z-1)^{4} =z^{4} -4z^{3} +6z^{2} -4z-1\\
\Longrightarrow z^{4} -4z^{3} +6z^{2} -4z-2=( z-1)^{4} -3\\
The\ equation\ boils\ down\ to\ finding\ the\ roots\ of\\
( z-1)^{4} =3\\
\Longrightarrow z-1=3^{\frac{1}{4}}\left( e^{\frac{2\pi ki}{4}}\right)\\
where\ k=0,1,2,3
\end{gather*}
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

The given expression can be rewritten as:
\begin{align*}
z^{4} - 4z^{3} + 6z^{2} - 4z - 2 = (z^{4} - 4z^{3} + 6z^{2} - 4z + 1) - 3
\end{align*}

where the first part can be expressed as
\begin{align*}
{4\choose 0}z^{4}(-1)^{0} + {4\choose 1}z^{3}(-1)^{1} + {4\choose 2}z^{2}(-1)^{2} + {4\choose 3}z^{1}(-1)^{3} + {4\choose 4}z^{0}(-1)^{4} 
\end{align*}

which equals $(z-1)^{4}$ due to the binomial theorem.

Can you take it from here?